# Python Split string by 1 and 3 spaces

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, list

Im wondering if its possible in python to split a string by 1 and 3 spaces at the same time. For example I have a `string:` `Hi There` and assume that this string is written in morse code. Each word is seperated by 3 spaces and each letter is seperated by 1 space.
`.... ..   - .... . .-. .`

is this possible in python ? if so, how can I do it?

Comment: What would you like to receive as the result of this? A list of lists?

Comment: Why you don't want to split by 3 spaces (words) at first, and then apply split by 1 space to each word?

Comment: @ShuzZzle: They clearly are working with morse-code as the **input**, not as output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just split two times; once on 3 spaces, then each word on the single space in a list comprehension:

```
[word.split(' ') for word in sentence.split('   ')]
```

This gives you nice nested list too; you wouldn't want to lose the delineation between words, after all.

Demo:

```
>>> sentence = '.... ..   - .... . .-. .'
>>> [word.split(' ') for word in sentence.split('   ')]
[['....', '..'], ['-', '....', '.', '.-.', '.']]
```

If you were to insist on one long list, just use a `word.split()` call to split on *arbitrary width* whitespace:

```
sentence.split()
```

This produces a list of individual morse letters, all jumbled together:

```
>>> sentence.split()
['....', '..', '-', '....', '.', '.-.', '.']
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question as asked,

```
In [17]: s = '.... ..   - .... . .-. .'
In [18]: s.split()
Out[18]: ['....', '..', '-', '....', '.', '.-.', '.']
```

Or if the word boundaries are indicated by some other character such as a tab (`\t`):

```
In [18]: [l for w in s.split('\t') for l in w.split()]
Out[18]: ['....', '..', '-', '....', '.', '.-.', '.']
```

... but you lose the word boundaries themselves, of course.

Comment: Then you may as well just use `s.split()` and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you could do splitting with `map`

```
sentence = '.... ..   - .... . .-. .'
splitted_sentence = map(lambda x: x.split(), sentence.split('   '))
splitted_sentence
Out[21]: [['....', '..'], ['-', '....', '.', '.-.', '.']]
```

`sentence.split('   ')` will split `sentence` into `list` of words, and `map` will apply `split` to each word.

Answer (score 0):

You could decide not to care about the two/three spaces and first split by a single space. The output list will be too long, but the entries where a space was are now all empty. These you could all filter out in one go.

In Python 3.x:

```
list(filter(None,'.... ..   - .... . .-. .'.split(' ')))
```

(Obviously, if you know where the space combinations will be you could also construct a regular expression)